# Passing variable value from one function to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have used 3  functions. getvalyear() and getvaltrimester() are used to get value of selected dropdown. getVal() gets id as parameter from the clicked button.

```
function getvalyear(ctrl1){    
    var sel = ctrl1.selectedIndex; 
    var selVal1 = ctrl1.options[sel].value;      
}

function getvaltrimester(ctrl2){
    var sel = ctrl2.selectedIndex; 
    var selVal2 = ctrl2.options[sel].value;
}

function getVal(clicked_id)
{

}
```

getvalyear() and getvaltrimester() function get's called from select menu as

```
Select Year:
       <select name="year" id="year"  style="width: 200px" onchange="getvalyear(this)">
          <option value="2014">2014</option>
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>   
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
        </select>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Select Trimester: 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="trimester" id="trimester" style="width: 200px" onchange="getvaltrimester(this)">
            <option value="1st">1st</option>
            <option value="2nd">2nd</option>
            <option value="3rd">3rd</option>
        </select>
```

getVal() function get's called on button click as

```
    <?php
      require('connect.php');
      $sql = "SELECT ictv_id,ictv_name, lb_name FROM ictv_details where region_id='1' and lb_type='DDC' ";
      $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
      echo "<div style='text-align: left'>";                   
      echo "<table>";
      echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Local Body</th><th>Absenteeism</th>
      <th>Creativity</th><th>Problem Solving</th><th>Submit</th></tr>";
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                  $ict_id= $row['ictv_id'];
                  $name= $row['ictv_name'];
                  $lb= $row['lb_name'];
      echo "<tr><form name=\"form$ict_id\" id=\"form$ict_id\"><td>".$name."</td><td>".$lb."</td>

    <td>
      <select name=\"absent$ict_id\" id=\"absent$ict_id\" style=\"width: 200px\">
        <option value></option>
        <option value=\"1\">1</option>
        <option value=\"2\">2</option>
        <option value=\"3\">3</option>
        <option value=\"4\">4</option>
        <option value=\"5\">5</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td>
      <select name=\"creative$ict_id\" id=\"creative$ict_id\" style=\"width: 200px\">
        <option value></option>
        <option value=\"1\">1</option>
        <option value=\"2\">2</option>
        <option value=\"3\">3</option>
        <option value=\"4\">4</option>
        <option value=\"5\">5</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td>
      <select name=\"problem$ict_id\" id=\"problem$ict_id\" style=\"width: 200px\">
        <option value></option>
        <option value=\"1\">1</option>
        <option value=\"2\">2</option>
        <option value=\"3\">3</option>
        <option value=\"4\">4</option>
        <option value=\"5\">5</option>
      </select>
    </td>

<td>
<input type=\"button\" name=\"submit$ict_id\"  id=\"submit$ict_id\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary \" onclick=\"getVal(this.id)\">

</td>
</form>

</tr>";

} 

      echo "</table><br /><br /></div>";
     // mysql_close();

  ?>
```

My query is how can I use Value of selVal1 and selval2 in getVal function without passing argument.

Comment: Why not use global variables then? Make selVal1 and selval2 as global.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, show us how these functions are called, that way you can probably avoid globals.

Comment: @SajibAcharya I made selVal1 and selVal2 as global variable but it's value aren't displayed in getval function

Comment: @stackuser did you try Rushee's solution?

Comment: @SajibAcharya I have tried but it didn't sort out my problem

Comment: @stackuser what is the error you are facing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var selVal1 = "";
var selVal2 = "";
function getvalyear(ctrl1){

  var sel = ctrl1.selectedIndex; 
  selVal1 = ctrl1.options[sel].value; 

}

function getvaltrimester(ctrl2){
   var sel = ctrl2.selectedIndex; 
   selVal2 = ctrl2.options[sel].value;
}

 function getVal(clicked_id)
 {
   alert(selVal1 );
   alert(selVal2 );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add those variables to a high level **scope**. You can make those vars as globals (I don't recommend that) or you can wrap your code in a **self executable function** that is a better practice.

Take a look:

```
(function(){
    var selVal1 = '',
    selVal2 = '';

    function getvalyear(ctrl1){
      var sel = ctrl1.selectedIndex; 
      selVal1 = ctrl1.options[sel].value; 
    }

    function getvaltrimester(ctrl2){
        var sel = ctrl2.selectedIndex; 
        selVal2 = ctrl2.options[sel].value;
    }

    function getVal(){
        console.log(selVal1);
        console.log(selVal2);
    }
})();
```

**Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/MYWGwj) with the code updates. (Attaching events using jQuery)**

Comment: @stackuser Do you have an error? Do you have more code than the posted? Note that you should wrap your complete code on the function. A fiddle with your code will help a lot.

Comment: It didn't displayed error. I just did alert("Hello World") but it didn't displayed in keeping any of the function

Comment: getVal function gets triggered on button click. I am using onclick function in button and it passes this button id to getVal function

Comment: my code snip is                                              <select name="year" id="year"  style="width: 200px" onchange="getvalyear(this)">     <input type="button" onclick=getval(this.id) />

Comment: @stackuser Yes, is ok. That is happening because now all your vars and functions are not globals. Having inline javascript in the HTML is also a bad practice, you should attach those events using javascript (or jquery). I have modified your fiddle please check it http://jsfiddle.net/fgLga46z/1/

Comment: @stackuser I have added jquery to your code, If you don't want use jquery please tell me and I will change it to pure JavaScript. Review the code and ask me for whatever you need.

Comment: visit this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4OrNmxnXdz_M0FveFA5M2dZMTA/view?usp=sharing  .

Answer (score 1):

your `getvalyear()` and `getvaltrimester()` both performs the same functionality so,it can be just a single function.

```
var selected_array = [];//array variable

function getvalyear(ctrl){    
    var sel = ctrl.selectedIndex; 
    selected_array.push(ctrl.options[sel].value);      
}

function getval(clicked_id)
{
    for(var i=0; i<selected_array.length; i++) {
      alert(selected_array[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope this you satisfy your needs.Here **[Working FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ManikandanArunachalam/6trnbzd4/)**

Check this option:
[image]

Comment: there are two select menu . I used different function to get value of selected option and using these values in function that fires on button click

Comment: Update your question When and where you call the function..I think this single function is enough ,so you can use this function for both the select options.